# No output for a certain range

Tags: java

I'm having the same troubles with my program again.

The issue this time is that the program doesn't output anything for between 59 and 20. The program just terminates. As far as I can tell, all the if statements are formatted the same way but maybe I just need some fresh eyes on it because my brain is blocking out the error

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LazyDaysCamp
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int temp;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("What's the current temperature?");
        temp = scan.nextInt();
        if (temp > 95 || temp < 20)
        {
            System.out.println ("Visit our shops!");
        } else if (temp <= 95)
            if (temp >= 80)
            {
                System.out.println ("It's good weather for swimming");
            } else if (temp >=60) 
                if (temp < 80)
                {
                    System.out.println ("It's good weather for tennis");
                } else if (temp >= 40)
                    if (temp < 60)
                    {
                        System.out.println ("It's good weather for golf");
                    } else if (temp >= 20)
                        if (temp < 40)
                        {
                            System.out.println ("It's good weather for skiing"); 
                        }
                    }
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know the if statements are a bit excessive as someone pointed out but I'm required to do so (cascading if). Otherwise I'd use logical operators.

Here's the output:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java LazyDaysCamp

What's the current temperature?
100
Visit our shops!

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: java LazyDaysCamp

What's the current temperature?
85
It's good weather for swimming

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: java LazyDaysCamp

What's the current temperature?
70
It's good weather for tennis

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: java LazyDaysCamp

What's the current temperature?
50

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: java LazyDaysCamp

What's the current temperature?
30

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: java LazyDaysCamp

What's the current temperature?
15
Visit our shops!

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that several of your if statements are unnecessary.  If temperature is `>= 80`, it cannot be anything other than `< 80` at the point when you check that it's `< 80`.  This is done several times.

The issue is that your else-if-statements are being placed as alternates to these unnecessary if-statements that will *always* be true.  As a result, the else-if condition is never even evaluated.

```
if (temp < 80) // this is unnecessary because it's previously checked, and is always true
{
    System.out.println ("It's good weather for tennis");
}
else if (temp >= 40) // this is attached to the true-if and therefore isn't evaluated
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies within the else statements.  For example, when you try '50'

```
else if (temp >=60)
```

That statement returns false, and doesn't even go to the following if statement, which means it has no chance of following the else of that statement to get the correct result.

I recommend just removing all the else's and just using if statements.

Comment: Furthermore, do not use consecutive if statements, use the && statement.

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Removing all else statements and replacing them with if statements is not exactly same.

Comment: @KirkBackus Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for your post. Regarding your comment: You can actually edit your answer and include the remark about `&&` statements right in it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your if statements do not have braces to denote their conditional blocks.  This makes it very hard to determine what you are actually trying to accomplish.  In Java braces can be omitted after an if statement if the next line contains the statement that should execute.  This is not the case in your scenario and the aforementioned convention is not best practice.  I would recommend using braces throughout your conditional statements to denote their separation.

Comment: This isn't necessarily an answer, but then again, OP isn't really clear on what exactly the question is.

Comment: @Vulcan I would consider this part A of the answer.  If there were braces it would be easier for them and us to figure out exactly what they are trying to do.  The second portion of the solution, Part B may be obvious if this suggestion is implemented.

Comment: I would agree with you (I prefer brackets too), but the issue here is actually simple logistics, and lies within an area where OP is using brackets.

Comment: I agree with using braces for readability. I also edited the post's indentation. (It's still pending review.)